# Illuminated rocker switch different wirings

Tags: switches

In the following links the illuminated rocker switch power terminal is shown as one of the further terminals, and accessories terminal is in the middle (brass is ground or neutral).

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/SPST-rocker-switch-wiring.php
http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/rocker-switches/0419782/
http://www.wiringdepot.com/blog/How-to-Wire-an-Illuminated-Rocker-Switch

Whereas in the following videos the power in terminal is the middle and the accessories terminal is one of the further terminal.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ndOlIgn1ys

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpcqgZaqTjk

I thought switch wiring is standardized. Does it depend on the particular switch or one of the two methods above is wrong?

Comment: Depends. Do you want the light to be always on, or only on when the accessory gets power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wiring ("pionout") for switches is NOT standardized. The correct wiring for each brand and model of switch is specified by the manufacturer. You CANNOT assume there is any sort of "standard" here.  There is not.

Answer (score 1):

Two answers.

1. Yes, pinout varies. Not all switches use the same order.
2. Wiring it can depend. Do you want the light to be always on, or only on when the accessory gets power? If you switch the power and accessory pin, the light will change.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvsTQ4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The one on the left always has the light on. The one on the right only turns on the light when the switch is "On".

Answer (score 0):

Get data sheets and instruction sheets for the products that you intend to use from the manufacturer. Go by that when deploying any particular product.

If you get into a mode of needing to find equivalent second sources it behooves you to get the same data sheets and information sheets for the comparable products and do a detailed analysis to determine second source equivalence.

Do not depend in various web sits and u-toob videos for information on how to make these determinations.